# Unable to run TensorFlow Lite example after importing the project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow-lite

I followed the instructions on this website: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/kerasnlp-tflite?hl=zh-cn#1 to import the examples/lite/examples/generative_ai folder into Android Studio. However, I encountered issues when trying to run the project. The instructions provided in the Readme.md didn't work as expected.

Could someone please guide me on how to properly set up and run the TensorFlow Lite example in Android Studio? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs58v.png)

Cloned the TensorFlow GitHub repository.
Navigated to the examples/lite/examples/generative_ai folder.
Imported the project into Android Studio as per the provided guidelines.
follow the Readme.md
Add the configuration but failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWVkh.png)
What I expected to happen:
I expected the project to import smoothly without any errors. After successful import, I could run the TensorFlow Lite example on an Android emulator or device.

What actually resulted:
I can't run the app and the default configuration is wrong. It seems that the instructions provided in the website are outdated or incorrect for my current environment. I'm stuck at this point and unsure about how to resolve these issues.

If anyone has encountered and overcome similar problems or knows the correct steps to run the TensorFlow Lite example in Android Studio, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!